# Show that an order relation can be defined for the set of points $(x,y)$ of a coordinate plane.

Tags: geometry

I Think I have to show that the following two axioms hold, I have already shown that multiplication of ordered pairs can be defined (as well as other axioms) showing that it is a field. Although I think this information is not necessary, seen as i am only asked to define an order relation.

> $$O1 \text{ Every pair } a,b \text{ of elements of F satisfies one and only one of the conditions }$$
> $$ a * b,\quad a = b,\quad b * a $$
>
> $$O2 \text{ If } a * b \text{ and } b * c \text{ then } a * c.$$

My first question is, what makes an ordered pair less than another ordered pair?

First I though in terms of distance from the origin, so that one point $P_1(x_1,y_1)$would be considered less than another $P_2(x_2,y_2)$by having  $\sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2} < \sqrt{x_2^2 + y_2^2} $, but $\sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2}$ could equal $\sqrt{x_2^2 + y_2^2} $ but $x_1 \neq x_2$ or $y_1 \neq y_2$

My next line of attack is thinking in terms of functions, such that $ y = f(x)$ so $(x,y) = (x,f(x))$ and hence one point is considered less in the plane if $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$, but there are holes in this, what function am I to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many orders that satisfy trichotomy and transitivity, your two axioms. One good one is the lexigraphic order, which is defined by:

$$(x_1,y_1)*(x_2,y_2)\iff x_1<x_2 \lor (x_1=x_2 \land y_1<y_2)$$

Comment: I was thinking about using this sort of idea, but for some reason didn't commit to it. Great stuff Rory :) +1

Comment: Hey Rory, I've done a little more research into orders and came across this one $(x_1,y_1)\leq(x_2,y_2)\iff (x_1<x_2 \text{ and }y_1 < y_2) \|or (x_1=x_2 \text{ and }  y_1 =y_2)$, it's called the product order. This one seems to be stronger than the lexicographic one.My only reason for looking into it, is when confronted with: is $(100,1) < (1,100)$?  The answer no, seems unsatisfactory. Whats even more so is that $(1,100) < (100,1)$ is true. Is there a reason not to use product over lexicographic? Thanks again.

Comment: The [product order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order) is not a total order. In particular, it does not satisfy your first axiom O1. Neither $(100,1)<(1,100)$ nor $(1,100)<(100,1)$ so none of the three possibilities in O1 is met. (you statement that $(100,1)<(1,100)$ is not true, since it is not true that $x_1<x_2$ here. [Lexigraphic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) is a total order and meet your axioms. That is a good reason to usually not use product order. Sometimes all you need is a simple partial order, then it suffices.

Comment: I see, a bit of late night stupidity on my part!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try ordering first based on the first coordinate in the pair, and if there is a tie, then break ties based on an ordering of the second coordinate in the pair.